# React state update from separate module. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot figure out how to update the state in react in the main component `App`.

So, I have a main component `App` that store all states from whole app. I want to manipulate with update of state from separate module `settingState`.

The chain logic of state update is the next:

1. Child component `MenuButtonOpen` do something and change the one of the state paramenters and push it as an argument to the middleware module `settingState`;
2. The middleware module `settingState` catch this parameter and trasfer it to the component `App` to make the state update of whole `App`.

Please, help me someone...

My stucture. It work, but does not update the state when I do something on the page:

/* APP */

```
import settingState from '../../view/settingState'
import MenuButtonOpen from '../menu-buttons/MenuButtonOpen'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      coordY: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState = ({
      toggle: settingState().toggle,
      coordY: settingState().coordY
    })
  }
 }
```

/* MIDDLEWARE SETTINGSTATE */

```
const settingState = (e, d) => {
    return ({
     toggle: e,
     coordY: d
    });
  };

  export default settingState;
```

/* SOME CHILD COMPONENT THAT MAKE A STATE UPDATE */

```
import settingState from '../../view/settingState'

class MenuButtonOpen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        settingState(
            e = true,
            d = window.pageYOffset
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: For one: setState is a function and hence you don't need an extra = sign `this.setState = ({` shoulf be `this.setState({` and secondly, componentDidMount is called only after initial render and hence you need to actually a listener and subscriber to check for updates to settingState

Comment: The second of your aswer is the main question. How I can make and integrate the listener for subscribing on settingState parameters update? @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to manipulate the `App` components state from a different component, you would need to pass a reference of `App` to each of the components that could modify its state, or pass a function that is bound to `App` and call that when you want a state update. This is however somewhat different that you would like to achieve as `settingState` would become useless as a separate component.

What you are trying to achieve is quite similar to the popular flux architecture/pattern used in react applications. With the flux pattern you would need to create a separate component called a `Data Store` to hold your data, which would be globally accessible, just like your `settingState`. Your `App` component would then listen to state changes within this store, just like if it was its own state. There are several libraries implementing this pattern. The most commonly used is probably [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/docs), but since it is pretty complex, I would recommend you to check out [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) or [Cartiv](https://github.com/yonatanmn/Cartiv). These libraries achieve similar functionalities in a really simple way.

Of course you can also implement something like this yourself, in order to do this you would need to create a singleton component, that is always there and does not render anything but only holds data. Your `App` component could then subscribe to it in order to see modifications. This would have a very similar functionality to that you have in the question. In order to subscribe to changes you could use [High-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Here is an example of a store's implementation that handles listeners automatically, and how you return a component wrapped into a HOC that listens to changes in the store:

```
export class Store {

  constructor() {
    this.listeners = [];
    this.listenerId = 0;
    this.state = {};
  }

  addChangeListener(func) {
    this.listeners[this.listenerId] = func;
    this.listenerId++;
    return this.listenerId - 1;
  }

  removeChangeListener(id) {
    if (id > 0) delete this.listeners[id];
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    this.listeners.map(listener => listener());
  }

  setState(nextState) {
    extend(this.state, this.state, nextState);
    this.componentWillUpdate();
  }

  getState() {
    return this.state;
  }
}

export function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, ...stores) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.listenerId = -1;
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      let data = {};
      stores.map(s => {
          extend(data, s.getState())
        }
      );
      this.state = {
        data: data
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.listenerId = stores.map(s => s.addChangeListener(this.handleChange));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      stores.map(s => s.removeChangeListener(this.listenerId));
    }

    handleChange() {
      let data = {};
      stores.map(s => {
          extend(data, s.getState())
        }
      );
      this.setState({
        data: data
      });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
```

Might not be a very good solution, the libraries linked above do a really good job at implementing data stores. This one is more of an example of how it could be implemented using HOCs. In this example, your `App` component would be used as `const AppWithSubscription = withSubscription(App, YourStore)`, where `YourStore extends Store`. I would still recommend checking out the libraries mentioned tho.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. High-Order Components is exacly what I need, but can we build a such component that will listen the changes in the some component?

Comment: You most certainly can. The page I linked gives you quite a few examples. Actually that is the point of having HOCs. There are many ways it can be implemented.

Comment: I added an example implementation to the answer now. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you want to use a middleware? I would suggest you just pass on a function as a prop to your Child component.

In the parent you create a function to update the state and pass it down to the child as prop.

```
import MenuButtonOpen from '../menu-buttons/MenuButtonOpen'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      coordY: 0
    };
  }

  updateState = (e, d) => {
      this.setState({
          toggle: e,
          coordY: d,
      })
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <MenuButtonOpen handleToggle={this.updateState} />
        </div>
      )
  }
 }
```

In the child you can access that function with `this.props.handleToggle` and call it with the arguments you would like to update your parent component with.

```
class MenuButtonOpen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handleToggle(true, window.pageXOffset)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.props.handleToggle(true, window.pageYOffset)} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I aslo know about this solution. But I really need to make a middleware for this case....

Comment: Then I would suggest you look into flux or redux. As the other post recommended.